# Reason for different API responses to request in node and chrome?

Tags: node.js, request

So I have a bunch of tracks from Spotify's API and I want their genres (which Spotify doesn't give) so for every track I make an API call to Last FM to get their top tags. Now this works for *most* tracks, I have to match the track name and artist as strings to last fm:

**Here's my problem**:
I do like this (pseudo:ish code):

```
let promises = spotifyTracks
      .map(track => rp({url: "http://lastfmapi.com/?artist="+track.artist+"?track="+track.name })
                .then(response => {
                    track.genre = response.genre;
                    return track;
                })
      );
return Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log('done!'));
```

Using [request promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise).

Now there a few tracks that currrently baffles me. Like 10 in 600. I get a response from lastFM saying:

```
{ error: 6, message: 'Track not found', links: [] }
```

To double check I printed the url used:

```
"http://lastfmapi.com/?artist="+track.artist+"?track="+track.name
```

Inside the then-call along with the response.

Now if I copied that url from my output and pasted it right into my chrome-browsers address-bar, the API finds the track!?!??!

**the actual example**

```
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.gettoptags&artist=pugh+rogefeldt&track=små+lätta+moln&autocorrect=1&api_key=141bed9ffc180dd9b07ac93b7e3b56d7&format=json
```

When it is called in my node-code I get

```
{ error: 6, message: 'Track not found', links: [] }
```

when called in the chrome address bar I get

```
{"toptags": {
    "tag":
        [
            {
                "count":100,
                "name":"swedish",
                "url":"https://www.last.fm/tag/swedish"
            },
            {
                "count":100,
                "name":"singer-songwriter",
                "url":"https://www.last.fm/tag/singer-songwriter"
            }, 
            ...
        ],
        "@attr":{
            "artist":"Pugh Rogefeldt",
            "track":"Små lätta moln"
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone got any idea what could be the reason behind this discrepancy?

Comment: I suspect it is character encoding. Their are some strange characters in the track field for your example. I'm not sure of the solution, but hopefully this leads yourself or another user to an answer.

Comment: Yes! It looks like you're right! I copied the url from chrome into vscode and noticed that 'å' changed into '%C3%A5'. So I replaced all the 'äåö'-letters with their strange counterparts! And now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome address bar will encode the string into URL for you, which will make your actual example become

```
method=track.gettoptags&artist=pugh+rogefeldt&track=sm%C3%A5+l%C3%A4tta+moln&autocorrect=1&api_key=141bed9ffc180dd9b07ac93b7e3b56d7&format=json
```

You should do the same thing in your node-code with `encodeURIComponent`